# Table collapses when shrunk below certain width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to make a table with fixed headers but cant seem to get it to work correctly...

I was wondering why the table collapses when the table shrinks below a certain width and if there is a solution to fixing it.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-fixed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-1">Make</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Model</th>
        <th class="col-md-3">Color</th>
        <th class="col-md-3">Year</th>
        <th class="col-md-3">Stuff</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-1">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-2">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell col-md-3">2000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the css:

```
.table-fixed {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 200px; /* this can vary */
}

.table-fixed thead {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
}

.table-fixed thead > tr, .table-fixed tbody > tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.table-fixed th, .table-fixed tbody td {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/OJVslUQ2AJ)

Comment: You are using bootstrap I guess? Probably because you use .col-md instead of .col-sm. Not sure. but give it a try.

Comment: P.S: If that doesn't work it's because of how your are 'display'ing your elements.

Comment: Make sure to include the code from your Bootply in your question. If for some reason the link changes/degrades, your question becomes invalid.

Comment: No problem. Now what do you mean "fixed headers"? Bootstrap is a responsive framework, so the concept of fixed kinda doesn't make sense. The data and headers are going to adjust depending on the current width of the device viewing the page, so having the headings fixed would cause alignment issues. Take a look at this http://www.bootply.com/FPhuRWFiQO to see how the table should work (responsive)

Comment: I think he means fixed as in position: fixed?

Comment: @DannyvanHolten Ok, but what does that mean when used with Bootstrap? Read my comment on why fixed makes no sense when using a responsive framework.

Comment: I know :) Don't get it either, but that would be my guess.

Comment: Sorry what i mean is that the header is fixed and the table body scrolls if there are a lot of items. So more like floating headers